# How to sum a slice of bytes reducing the possibility of overflow

Tags: string, rust, sum, byte, slice

I have an ASCII string slice and I need to compute the sum of all characters when seen as bytes.

```
let word = "Hello, World";
let sum = word.as_bytes().iter().sum::<u8>();
```

I need to specify the type for sum, otherwise Rust will not compile. The problem is that `u8` is a too small type, and if the sum overflows the program will panic.

I'd like to avoid that, but I cannot find a way to specify a bigger type such as `u16` or `u32` for example, when using `sum()`.

I may try to use `fold()`, but I was wondering if there is a way to use `sum()` by specifying another type.

```
let sum = word.as_bytes().iter().fold(0u32, |acc, x| acc + *x as u32);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `map` to cast each byte to a bigger type:

```
let sum: u32 = word.as_bytes().iter().map(|&b| b as u32).sum();
```

or

```
let sum: u32 = word.as_bytes().iter().cloned().map(u32::from).sum();
```

The reason why you can't sum to `u32` using your original attempt is that the [`Sum` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html) which provides it has the following definition:

```
pub trait Sum<A = Self> {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = A>;
}
```

Which means that its method `sum` returns by default the same type as the items of the iterator it is built from. You can see it's the case with `u8` by looking at its [implementation of `Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html#impl-Sum%3Cu8%3E):

```
fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> u8
where
    I: Iterator<Item = u8>,
```

Comment: What's the difference of your solutions compared to the fold one, in terms of memory usage and performance?

Comment: It'd be good to touch on why OP can't do `word.as_bytes().iter().sum::<u32>()` as they tried originally.

Comment: I just tried and looked at the assembly. When compiling with optimization, the compiler indeed [generates exactly the same code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=6bc9e1d988e1f00fc1b9d5eca59ddc95). For private functions, the compiler simply removes one of them since they are identical. When I tried with a fixed string, the compiler computed the sum at compile time, and the only code emitted for the function was `movd eax, 1234; ret` or similar, so I added code to generate a random string.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes please, would be interesting to know.

Comment: @SvenMarnach if you drop the `main` off and make the functions public, you can avoid that inlining.

Comment: @ljedrz thanks, it would have been interesting to know the reason behind this decision.

Comment: @Nick TBH, I don't know why the widening versions haven't been added. I assume it's just that no one has done it yet. Maybe you can submit a pull request to add them!